# dismissPopUp is not recognized

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, appkit

Assuming button1 is an NSPopUpButton
Assuming menu attached to button1 is displayed and being tracked.

[[button1 cell] dismissPopUp]    --- dismissPopUp is not recognized.

Why is the dismissPopUp method not recognized?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because NSCells don't respond to `dismissPopUp` messages.

If you're getting this as an exception at run time, make sure `button1` really is a pop-up button—that is, make sure you hooked up that outlet to the right object in IB, or that you assigned the right object there if you created it in code. In the latter case, use the debugger to examine the variable.

If this is just a warning you're getting from the compiler, it's probably because `cell` is a method of NSControl (NSPopUpButton's grand-superclass), and is typed as returning an NSCell. The compiler has no way of knowing that this particular control will return an NSPopUpButtonCell. The solution is to assign the result of the `cell` message to a variable typed as `NSPopUpButtonCell *`, and then send the `dismissPopUp` message to the object in that variable:

```
NSPopUpButtonCell *cell1 = [button1 cell];
[cell1 dismissPopUp];
```

If you still get the warning, you'll need to add an explicit cast in front of the `[button1 cell]` expression.